# How to deduce the poles and residues just by looking?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$f(z)=\frac{5z-2}{z(z-1)}$$

Then $f$ has simple poles at $0,1$ with $\text{Res}(f,0)=2$ and $\text{Res}(f,1)=3$.

How can one tell this?

The way I did it was to say $z(z-1)=z^2-z$ which vanishes at $0,1$ yet its derivative $2z-1$ does not vanish at either $0,1$ and also $5z-2$ doesn't vanish at $0,1$ so $f(z)$ has simple poles at $0,1$ and then $\text{Res}(f,0)=\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{5z-2}{z-1}=2$ and similarly for the other residue.

Is there a better/quicker way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By partial fractions,

$$f(z) = \frac{2}{z} + \frac{3}{z -1 }$$

Hence, the residues are $2$ and $3$, respectively: The first terms of the Laurent series expansions around $0$ and $1$ are written above, and the coefficients are the residues.

---

Another way, for simple poles. Write

$$f(z) = \frac 1 z \left(\frac{5z - 2}{z - 1}\right) = \frac 1 z g(z)$$

where $g$ is holomorphic at $0$. Since it's holomorphic, it has a Taylor series around $0$, with constant term $g(0) = 2$. Then the Laurent series expansion of $f$ starts with $2/z$, so the residue is $2$.

Comment: Oh that is very nice thank you. Is there generally a best method to try and approach finding poles and residues or does it depend more on the function and becoming familiar with spotting tricks?

Comment: @Sam I added another technique that works for simple poles.